# Значение input поместить в значение ссылки без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть страница с опросом test.php. После прохождения опроса, без перезагрузки выдается результат.

```
<div class="test__question-name">
  Сколько вам лет?
</div>

<input type="number" class="input-name" name="user-age" placeholder="Введите ваш возраст (например, 34)" />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-test">Ответить</button>
```

Как пометить значение `value` из `input`a в ссылку на этой же странице `test.php`, без перезагрузки страницы.
К примеру:

```
<a href="http://test.ru/r=тут значение">Посмотрите совет</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var link = "http://test.ru/";
$('#submit').on('click', function() {
    var $input = $('input[name="user-age"]').val();
    if ( $input ) {
        $('#answer').attr('href', link + "r=" + $input).show(); 
    } else {
        alert('input missing');
    }
    
})
```

```css
#answer{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test__question-name">
     Сколько вам лет?
    </div>

   <input type="number" class="input-name" name="user-age" placeholder="Введите ваш возраст (например, 34)" />
   <button id="submit" type="button" class="btn btn-test">Ответить</button>
   
 <a id="answer" href="">Посмотрите совет</a>
```